# How to read special character?

Tags: java

I have a record like below

```
A^]B^]C^]^]^]
```

record fields are separated by `^]` and its a special character. I cant see this value while doing `cat` in linux but if `-A` operator.

Want to know how can I read such record with special character (`^]`) as field separator in Java?

What should I mention for field separator to detect it?

Comment: Conventionally `^]` would be how you would enter the ASCII `GS` control character; i.e. 0x1D or U+001D.

Comment: *"I cant see this value while doing cat in linux but if -A operator."*  - Try using `od -x ...` to see the byte values in hexadecimal.

Comment: @StephenC, how did you convert to U+001D ? hex of ^ is 5E and ] is 5D

Comment: The first 128 codepoints in Unicode are identical to ASCII codes.

Comment: @StephenC, but how did you convert this 5E5D to U+001D ?

Comment: I didn't.  The `^]` that you see is actual the display form that `cat -A` is producing.  The actual character in the file is a `GS` control code whose binary value is the byte `0x1D`.  If you read this with a `Reader` and the correct character encoding, you will get the `U+001D` codepoint.

Comment: If you are feeding the output of `cat -A` to a Java program, then you will need to unpick the `^` notation that the former is generating.  A better idea would be to NOT use `cat -A` ...

Comment: I don't understand.  In what sense does Java recognize field separators?  Are you talking about a specific API?  Are you putting this character into your source code?  Certainly, I don't want >my< source code to include character that I cannot see in a text editor.  And you don't need to.  Use `\uxxxx` syntax as per Andreas's answer.

Comment: @StephenC.last question sir, why not java able to identify ^] as field separator ? I can't see this character , but while code compilation don't you think java should identify this hidden special character and do the needful ?

Comment: For example, If I give ### a field separator, java code will identify it and process. But dont you think this special character should be identified too because its something which is already there in file. No ?

Comment: It would be a VERY bad idea if Java source code could contain characters that you cannot see.  The `0x1D` character is a non-printing / non-displayable character ... on a lot of output devices.  For instance on >your< terminal when you `cat` ed the file.

Comment: Anyway ... Java is what it is ... and what you or I >think< about it is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

`^]` is known as [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation), and means byte value 29, which is a non-displayable ASCII/Unicode control character. That's why you normally can't see it.

In Java, you can use octal escape or Unicode escape to represent such a character:

- Octal escape: `\35`
- Unicode escape: `\u001D`

If you read in a line of text, ending up with `s = "A^]B^]C^]^]^]"`, where `^]` represents the special byte 29 character, then you can get the field values by splitting the string using `s.split("\35", -1)`.

Here is code showing it:

```java
String line = "A\u001DB\u001DC\u001D\u001D\u001D";
System.out.println("line = \"" + line + '"');
System.out.println("line.length() = " + line.length());
String[] fields = line.split("\35", -1);
for (String s : fields)
    System.out.println('"' + s + '"');
```

*Output*

```
line = "ABC"
line.length() = 8
"A"
"B"
"C"
""
""
""
```

The code used Unicode escape to build the string, but octal escape in the `split()`, just to show that they are the same character.

As you can see, the string is 8 characters long, but only the 3 displayable characters can be seen when printing it.

Splitting does however show that there are 6 fields (separated by 5 separators).